# Download button for mobile apps

Tags: maximo

Why there is no Download button for mobile application tables in Maximo( Asset Management 7.6.0.3)?
If I want to download the contents listed in a table, how to do it

Comment: By "Mobile application" do you mean DataSplice or Maximo Everyplace or Maximo Anywhere or EZ Max Mobile or something else?

Comment: @Preacher **IBM Maximo Spatial Asset Management 7.6.0.3**